# Parallax effect only working on background image and not text

Tags: html, css

I'm currently following the [tutorial on parallax effects](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp) on W3Schools. Basically, I have it so where the parallax is scrolling over my background correctly, but it's not scrolling over the text as well.

I tried a lot of things but it still doesn't work. I also saw one other post about this issue, but their code differed a lot from mine so it was hard to understand.

Here is the image of what is happening (the words are scrolling up with the page):
[image: words are scrolling up with the page]

Here's my code:

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

ul{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    margin: 12px auto;
    list-style: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index:10;
    top: 0;
}

ul, li{
    display: inline-table;
}

li{
    margin: 10px 30px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #42385d;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
}


.navbar{
    background-color: #ffcfda;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ffcfda;
    z-index: 10;
    height: 70px;
    top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#parallax{
    background-image: url("pinkbackground.jpg");
    min-height: 100vh;

    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}

.transition{
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #42385d;
    width: 100%;
}
.intro-text{
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    color: #42385d;
    padding: 37vh;    
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
    position: relative;
    background-attachment: initial;
}

.question{
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;   
    color: #42385d;
    font-weight: bolder;
    padding-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <title>schpiel - Applying, Made Easier</title>
    <!--meta data-->
    <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name = "description" content =
     "schpiel, like the name implies, makes applying easier. 
    no, it doesn't sound like that? :(. Using our new autofill 
    feature, with one click you can apply instantly!">

    <!--styling-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Mono:ital,wght@1,300&family=Roboto+Slab&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="icon" href="https://i.imgur.com/RoPgdJh.jpg">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="navigation">
        <nav class="navbar";>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a>
                        Home
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a>
                        About
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a>
                        Contact
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    <div id="parallax">
        <div class="intro-text">
            text 
                <br>
              here
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="transition"></div>
    <section id="whatIsSchpiel">
        <div class="question">
            What is schpiel?
            </div>
        <div class="answer">
            sscsdafads
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
<footer>
</footer>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Could you post your HTML code too? That will make it easier to debug your code. You can just [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72638612/edit) your question and use a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: I just added it to  snippet!

Comment: I'm still struggling to understand what you're trying to achieve. Your code works fine in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/camelopardalus/pen/ExQBKKp) (I only changed the background image to see what's happening). The effects looks the same as in the tutorial.

Comment: So the background is working, my concern is that is there any way to apply the parallax effect to the text itself on the screen without making the text itself an image? Thanks for any help!